# Find the size of a UIView from its layout constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a xib file, as shown below. I need to find out how tall this is going to be with its auto-layout constraints. The text is all dynamic and wrapping. The width of the whole view can vary as well.

[image: IB]

When the view's added to a view controller everything's in the right place, so I'm confident the constraints are all set up correctly, but the problem is I want to synchronously instantiate this view, tell it to set itself up and then ask it what it's total frame is going to be.

I've tried things along the lines of

```
let view = MyView.loadFromNib()

view.putMyTextOnAllTheLabels()

view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
view.setNeedsLayout()
view.layoutIfNeeded()

let fixedWidth: CGFloat = 100

let size = CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, CGFloat.max)

let desiredFrame = view.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(sizeToAssessWith, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow)
```

The desired frame never seems to be correct though. It's not the same as the frame I get when the view is actually added to a view.

What would be really useful, would be if there was some kind of callback or way of getting a callback when all of the views and the subviews with subviews have all decided on their final frames, as far as I can tell if I call setNeedsUpdateConstraints or any of the lines that follow that in my sample code, these don't seem to apply any constraints synchronously, if I inspect the position of my labels straight after calling these methods they are all in completely the wrong places.

So how am I supposed to find the size auto-layout is going to make this view?

Comment: You might be able to achieve what you need by creating custom controls and overriding IntrinsicContentSize and adding a callback there.